# R dbEscapeStrings doesnt appear to work as expected

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

Struggling to escape a string with a single quote mark so I can query DB.

Following examples from documentation has me more confused:

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RMySQL/versions/0.10.20/topics/dbEscapeStrings
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RMySQL/RMySQL.pdf

The example states:

```
tmp <- sprintf("SELECT * FROM emp WHERE lname = %s", "O'Reilly")  
dbEscapeStrings(con, tmp)
```

As far as I'm aware this will (and does) generate incorrect sql:
`select * from emp where lname = O'Reilly`

I tried adding quotes around the `%s`:

```
tmp <- sprintf('SELECT * FROM emp WHERE lname = "%s"', "O'Reilly")  
escaped_query <- dbEscapeStrings(con, tmp)
```

tmp: `select * from emp where lname = \"O'Reilly\"`
escaped_query : `select * from emp where lname = \\\"O\\'Reilly\\\"`

I believe I need to get the following output:
`select * from emp where lname = "O\'Reilly"`

Am I miss understanding something?

Comment: Never use `sprintf` for generating queries: even inadvertent sql injection can occur due to unicode or several other things. While there is `sqlInterpolate`, I strongly prefer using [parameter binding](https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/#parameterized-queries).

Answer (score 0):

I recommend strongly against `sprintf` (or `paste` or `glue(.)`, though `glue_sql(.)` is reasonable). My preference is parameter binding.

```r
dbGetQuery(con, "SELECT * FROM emp WHERE lname = ?", params = list("O'Reilly") )
```

More of the reasoning behind this (inadvertent SQL injection) and methods to fix it (`sqlInterpolate`, `dbBind`) can be found here: https://db.rstudio.com/best-practices/run-queries-safely/

BTW, string-literals in SQL are usually denoted with single-quotes, not doubles, so you should be seeing something like

```r
DBI::sqlInterpolate(con, "select * from abc where lname ?name", name="O'Reilly")
# <SQL> select * from abc where lname 'O''Reilly'
```